# WooCommerce REST: Nonce verification failed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I am getting this Nonce verfication failed, all api's working fine, I am only facing issue when signing up new customer, existing customer can login with no issue , Just only sign up. seeking some help to resolve this issue.

**Request**
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/customers?consumer_key=ck_consumer_key&consumer_secret=cs_consumer_secret

**Body**
`{"email":"[john.doe@example.com](mailto:john.doe@example.com)","first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","username":"john.doe","password":"Pas$w0rd","billing":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","company":"","address_1":"969 Market","address_2":"","city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postcode":"94103","country":"US","email":"[john.doe@example.com](mailto:john.doe@example.com)","phone":"(555) 555-5555"},"shipping":{"first_name":"John","last_name":"Doe","company":"","address_1":"969 Market","address_2":"","city":"San Francisco","state":"CA","postcode":"94103","country":"US"}}`

**Response**:
`{"code":"nonce_verification_failed","message":"Nonce verification failed","data":{"status":400}}`

Comment: What about using v3 API?  https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?consumer_key=ck_consumer_key&consumer_secret=cs_consumer_secret

Comment: @sagar Same result

Comment: What's the code that is sending the payload to the API?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with Plugin, I had to enable/disable plugins to make it work [know more about](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/22876)